# Inserting elements at specific locations in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A`. I want to insert elements according to sublists. For example, I want to insert `0` in `A[0]` at location `0`. Similarly, I want to insert `1` in `A[1]` at location `0`. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

A=[[1, 2, 3],[0, 2, 3],[0, 1, 3],[0, 1, 2]]

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    A=A[i].insert(i,0)
    print(A)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A=A[i].insert(i,1)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],[1, 0, 2, 3],[2, 0, 1, 3],[3, 0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: [list.insert](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) returns `None` so `A = A[i].insert(i,i)` overwrites your list as `None`

Comment: Now when you understood the cause of the error, I see you've imported `numpy`, are you also searching for a numpy solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doc:

> methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list
> have no return value printed – they return the default `None`.

But, nevertheless, inserting in a loop is not efficient as it have to shift all remaining elements rightward; use list comprehension instead:

```
A = [[i] + A[i] for i in range(len(A))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

A=[[1, 2, 3],[0, 2, 3],[0, 1, 3],[0, 1, 2]]

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    A[i].insert(0,i)
print(A)
```

Output:

```py
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 2, 3], [2, 0, 1, 3], [3, 0, 1, 2]]
```